# Add Marker on Narivescript-vue Android using @nativecript/google-maps

Tags: google-maps-markers, nativescript-vue

i try to add a marker with Nativescript-vue using @nativescript/google-maps package, bu it says map.addMarker is not function

```
onReady(event) {

    this.mapView = event.object;

    this.addMarker(this.mapView, this.markerOptions)

},

    addMarker(map, markerOptions) {

        const marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

        // You can further customize the marker if needed
        // For example: marker.icon = 'res://icon';

        return marker;

    },
```